# Downloading File from database with CreateExportDisplay

Tags: cuba-platform

I read in the documentation the "Downloading Files" section that serves to download a file to the user's computer. For it is based on CreateExportDisplay with FileDescriptor, my problem is that I have stored the files in the database in a blob field, I want to download them from the database to the user's computer, is there any implementation in CreateExportDisplay to do?

Answer (score 1):

You can use the standard implementation of ExportDataProvider - ByteArrayDataProvider that provides byte array:

```java
public class BlobFileBrowse extends AbstractLookup {
    @Inject
    protected Table<BlobFile> blobFilesTable;

    @Inject
    protected ExportDisplay exportDisplay;

    public void downloadContent() {
        BlobFile blobFile = blobFilesTable.getSingleSelected();

        exportDisplay.show(new ByteArrayDataProvider(blobFile.getContent()),
                "my-blob.dat", ExportFormat.OCTET_STREAM);
    }
}
```

Also you can implement your own ExportDataProvider and use it with ExportDisplay.